Share iPhone Hotspot through USB with Windows without installing iTunes
I followed this guide to share my iPhone internet connection with Windows:

Downloaded iTunes from https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ (not the Microsoft Store version, scrolled to "Looking for other versions?" and clicked Windows). This file was named iTunes64Setup.exe.

Used 7Zip to extract the AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi file from the .exe file above.

Run the AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi installer and followed the instructions.


After restarting and connecting my iPhone, the internet doesn't work.
When I access the control panel, I see a device named AppleUSBEthernet with a ⚠ sign and a message stating that the device drivers are not installed.
How can I resolve this issue?


Go back to 7Zip and open up the AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi installer itself.

Extract all of the files inside into a local folder, e.g. ~\Downloads\AppleMobileDeviceSupport64

Go back to the Device Manager > AppleUSBEthernet, right click, Properties > Update drivers.

Choose to select the driver files manually and select the folder you extracted the files in step 2. Ok.

This should now install the correct drivers. You should now see the Apple Mobile Device Ethernet device under the Network Adapters list in Device Manager. If not, restart again to make sure.


